# CakePHP email not sending but showing in debug mode

Tags: debugging, email, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

My CakePHP should send an email when a button is clicked, however it doesn't. Also, the email will be displayed as a flash message if I run it in debug mode: (`$this->Email->delivery = 'debug';`).

Note: Email is set up to set up to use PHP mail() function.

#### Code to call the email function:

```
$this->_sendUpdateEmail( $this->Auth->user('id'), $about_id );
```

#### Email function

```
function _sendUpdateEmail($from_user_id, $about_id) {
    $fromUser = $this->User->read(null, $from_user_id);

    $users = $this->User->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('User.distribution =' => 1)
    ));

    # loop to send email to all users who are marked as on the distribution list
    for($i = 0, $size = sizeof($users); $i < $size; ++$i) { 
        $user = $users[$i]['User'];

        $this->Email->from = $fromUser['User']['email'];
        $this->Email->replyTo = $fromUser['User']['email'];
        $this->Email->to = $user['email'];
        $this->Email->subject = 'Test email';
        $this->Email->template = 'update';
        $this->Email->sendAs = 'both'; // both = html and text

        $this->set('user', $user);
        $this->set('about', $about_id);

        $this->Email->send();
        $this->Email->reset();
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why the emails show in debug mode but won't actually send?

Comment: are you running this offline on localhost or aserver? How are you sure it isn't *sending*? You just might not be *receiving*.

Comment: It is now running on an internal server running apache on port 8080 because IIS is also running on port 80. During development, it was running on localhost locally on my computer but I only used the `debug` mode. My inbox is receiving other emails if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason why my emails were not sending was because there was no mail server configured on the web server my CakePHP was running on so there was no way to route the emails. However, this meant they would show up in the debug because they were generated successfully, just not sent.

In the end, I ended up using my company's Exchange mail server using the SMTP settings.

#### Code to use SMTP to send CakePHP emails

```
$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(        
    'port'=>'25',         
    'timeout'=>'30',        
    'host' => '192.168.0.244',       
);

// Other email code here, e.g. from and to etc...

$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that mail server is not set right  Linux  comes built in with mail sending functionality but not windows (no idea on mac). look into smtp options as u can easily setup smtp email sender on Windows

[Setting up smtp windows - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.webadmin.doc/topics/c_config_email_smtp_win.htm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.webadmin.doc/topics/c_config_email_smtp_win.htm)

and

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1290/Sending-A-Message-Using-SMTP